# Kicad 6 Global Label: Both are attached to the same items; one will be used in the netlist

Tags: kicad

My Schematic has a fuse and a varistor, and then the mains line continues to some relays:
[image]

Is there a way to tell Kicad that certain components should be placed after the varistor?

Currently the rules checker is giving this error:

```
Warning: Both 220VAV(N) and N_IN are attached to the same items; 220VAC(N) will be used in the netlist
```

Full project schematics:

Comment: Consider a net tie.

Comment: I would just use one net lable for the AC Neutal connection.  Electrically, it doesn't matter what order you show items connected on the schematic.  The arrangement of connections along a wire on the schematic has no bearing on how things are routed on the PC board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a warning.  If you are sure that this is what you want, then you can right-click on the warning in the ERC dialog and select "Ignore this warning" to suppress the message.

If you want `N_IN` to be connected to the varistor and `220VAC(N)` to be connected to pin 1 of the power supply, then you can use a net-tie between pin 1 and the varistor to explicitly separate the nets.